# passing arguments in onserverclick

Tags: c#, asp.net, repeater, eval

While using this line of code, I get the error

CS1040: Preprocessor directives must appear as the first non-whitespace character on a line

This code is under  tag and inside an asp:Repeater control

```
<td valign="bottom" width="130">
<%# Eval("Quantity")%>+ in stock<br />
<input class="textbox" maxlength="2" name="Quantity" size="2" type="text" value="1" />
                    <br />

<a id="A1" class="positive" runat="server"
onserverclick='addtocart(<%#Eval("ProductDescriptionId")%>,Quantity)'> Add to Cart</a>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

since onserverclick is evaluated on server side the # is being considered as C# directive. you can replace `<%#Eval("ProductDescriptionId")%>` with something like `DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"ProductDescriptionId")`.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure the `<%# %>` spans the entire attribute like so:

```
<a id="A1" class="positive" runat="server" 
   onserverclick='<%# "addtocart("+Eval("ProductDescriptionId").ToString()+",Quantity)"%>'>
```

Alternatively, you can use the built-in formatting on the `Eval` method:

```
<a id="A1" class="positive" runat="server" 
   onserverclick='<%# DataBinder.Eval( Container.DataItem, "ProductDescriptionId", "addtocart({0},Quantity)")%>'>
```

Comment: @user478636 What exactly doesn't work? You get the same error or is there something else not working?

Comment: well i am using linkbutton, it was more simple than what i was trying to do.